# Using java gnu serialport classes

Tags: java, gnu

Is there any way that I can import gnu.io.serialport classes?
I trying to do a serial communication and looks a bit hard to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had good luck with [rxtx](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port) on windows. supposed to work on [linux](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_Linux) also.

Comment: RXTX is *the* way to do serial port communication in Java, there's no other sensible option that I've come across. Has worked fine for me in Windows, Linux, Mac and Solaris.